# Copy from remote server to my laptop via ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, unix, centos

I am on centos server (via SSH) and I don't want to open file manager to copy dump file. What comand whould I use (scp or what) to copy that file from remote server directly to my comp.

like

```
cp ssh://user@server/app/dump.dat /home/
```

**UPD**

even more interested in how to copy file from my ssh session while I am on server back to my PC (of course I can logout or open new terminal tab or start up SSH server on PC)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scp your_username@remotehost.edu:foobar.txt /some/local/directory
```

[This Reference](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php) may help.

Comment: and how to use scp vice versa when I am on my remote server?

Comment: @fl00r: Start the SSH server on your PC, then use `scp`

Comment: as I thought :) But I don't want to start ssh server. thx

Comment: If you're behind a firewall or behind NAT the only way without setting up port forwarding is to use a 'client pull' system (scp run locally) or to tunnel something back down through the SSH channel with SSH's port tunneling.  What you'd use for that is anyone's guess, but you'd need to start _some_ form of server on your local machine - be it sshd, ftpd, or whatever.

Comment: unless the terminal you are using supports something like zmodem then you could use sz to send the file as if you were on a slow serial connection... *smirk*

Answer (score 3):

```
$ scp user@server:/app/dump.dat /home/
```

For a path relative to your home dir miss out the first /

Take a look at the `scp` man page for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

rsync is generally a better option. It is restartable, for one thing. Also, it is generally faster. See `man rsync` for tons of options.

```
rsync -abvz your_username@remotehost.edu:foobar.txt /some/local/directory
```

rsync is probably configured to use ssh by default, but if you want to be extra careful you can do

```
rsync -abvz -e ssh your_username@remotehost.edu:foobar.txt /some/local/directory
```

Answer (score 0):

**syntax:**

> sudo  -r scp file username@IP address or hostname:Destination

**example:**

> scp -r /media/disk/summer_pics/ mike@192.168.1.1:"/var/www/Summer 2008/"

[reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/TransferFiles)